# Android simulating play/pause button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, keyevent, android-context

I'm trying to make my application open up Google Play Music and then simulate a play/pause command. My application is able to start Google Play Music successfully, but the `downIntent` and `upIntent` KeyEvents are never broadcast. I suspect this is because calling the method just invokes the method on my main class and not Play Music itself. What's the proper way to broadcast these KeyEvents to Play Music?

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
startActivity(intent);

Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent);
sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, null);

Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent);
sendOrderedBroadcast(upIntent, null);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a very helpful buddy who pointed me in the right direction.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
intent.putExtra("command", "togglepause");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This seems to work well on Android 4.x, but I have not tested it on 5.x.

Comment: Useless, this controls single app that may not be present.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control the music player (the current playing one) there is a way to send KeyEvents to it:

```java
if (mAudioManager == null) mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode);
mAudioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(event);
```

Note: it needs to have minSdk 19 or more.

Comment: This is the only cross-application solution I've found that works without INJECT_EVENTS permission.

Comment: In some cases you might need to follow up with a KeyEvent.ACTION_UP depending on target app's implementation.

Comment: Wow, I just spent DAYS trying to find this, Just tried it and BAM! Wish I could drop 100 upvotes on this

Answer (score 0):

In case you're able to use an [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service), you can use its [performGlobalAction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#performGlobalAction(int)) method with a [GLOBAL_ACTION_KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#GLOBAL_ACTION_KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) argument, available from API level 31 onwards.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, for security reasons.  EXTRA_KEY_EVENT doesn't do what you think it does-  it does not send key events to the system.

Comment: Ah, is there any way at all for my app to achieve what I'd like to do? Open Play Music > Play/Pause

Comment: This is not true, please see my answer for a solution to target a specific app.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to target a specific app, this works, and you don't even have to launch the app.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE)).setPackage(packageName), null);
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE)).setPackage(packageName), null);
```